# Image of the week: how to see more info?

Tags: support, feature-request, featured-photo

I think the image of the week is great, and I often see an image that I would like to know more about, or see in a larger size. I expected that clicking on the image would take me to the original entry, where the photographer might have made some notes of what the photo is of and how/where it was taken, such as:

"Photo of *very rare animal*, taken in *exotic location* with *lens model* on a *camera model*. 1/125, f/8, iso 200."

This information is not included in the Hall of Fame, and there is no easy way to see where the photo is within the long list entries for that particular week.

Is there an easy way to do this? If not, could it be considered as a feature?

Answer (score 2):

Good idea. There are sometimes some comments, exposure info or link to a larger version of the image. We could probably copy that info to the Hall of Fame.

Comment: How should we proceed with a feature request for this? Was tagging it sufficient? (I will mark as answer soon, just giving it a little more time in case someone knows of a way to see the info that I do not.)